# A charge has electric fields radiating outwards, does that mean the net electric field is 0?

Tags: electric-fields

Since a charge has electric fields radiating outwards, do the electric fields cancel out and create 0 net electric field?

Comment: The surface of a bowling ball has area elements in all possible directions. Does that mean its net surface area is zero?

Comment: Yes, that is interesting. the normal points down at the bottom of the bowling ball but is supposed to be positive since it points out of the surface

Comment: Although the normal points in the negative direction at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the superposition principle to add electric field vectors *at the same point*, but not at different points.

When we say that the fields are "radiating out" from a (positive) electric charge, we mean that at a point located north of the charge, the electric field will point north; at a point south of the charge, the electric field will point south; at a point east, the field will point east; at a point west, the field will point west; etc.

Since we do not add the fields at *different* spatial locations, these electric field vectors (located at a point north, a point south, a point east, and a point west) do not add and so do not cancel.

Comment: Is one electric field line equal to E = k*q/r^2? It seems like all the radiating electric field lines equal that. Although when we determine the electric field line to a point, we only draw one field line towards it.

Comment: @Anna, electric field lines represent an arbitrary quantity of electric flux. You can use whatever value of electric flux you want, but you should be consistent in any given drawing and make every field line represent the same flux. (You shouldn't have field lines that represent different fluxes at different distances from the source charges, as your proposal requires).

Comment: No, I am saying that we usually draw one field line from a point charge to a point P to represent the electric field but we draw several radiating out of the point charge. But both fields are equal even though the field line to point P only has one line

Comment: @Anna The field lines are just a visual representation of what is really going on mathematically. What really happens is that at every point $P$, there is an electric field vector. If we have one positive point charge at the origin $O$, then the *magnitude* of the electric field at $P$ is $kq/r^2$, where $r$ is the distance between $O$ and $P$, and the *direction* of the field at $P$ points along the line from $O$ to $P$, away from the charge. When you draw field lines, you are just creating a way to visualize this, by drawing lines connecting the electric field vectors at different points.

Comment: So, it does not make sense to assign a single value with an electric field line (or ask what a field line is equal to). Rather, you should ask about the electric field magnitude and direction at a *point* in space. An electric field line intersects the electric field at many points.